# Do people fundraise to help someone buy a camera?

Tags: video, video-recording, camera, photos

I have been borrowing my library's camera the past few months and am getting sick of it. I want to buy my own camera, but the camera I want costs around $1600. I do not have that money but really want to get a camera to embark on a film project that would mean a lot to me and has an inspirational message. Can organizations, schools, and individuals provide funds or grants to help?

Comment: I suggest starting with a smartphone for $20, does not even have to be connected to the cellular network. Or any used consumer camera off eBay for around $100 or less. Build a portfolio, then maybe get some paid customers, then you will have money for a bigger camera.

Answer (score 2):

I remember when I was in high school I used to borrow their Canon 600D to use over the weekends. I loved it, but it was upsetting to have to return it every Monday. Like you, I couldn't afford to buy one at the time.

It wasn't until I got a casual retail job that was able to buy my first camera.

Now I'm a little older and have a steady(ish) income, I'm able to lease more expensive cameras and pay them off over time.

I'd argue that if you're after an individual/organisation to offer you a grant, you'd need a solid portfolio to convince them to do so. If no-one seems interested, then I'm afraid you'll need to wait and buy one yourself.

It doesn't need to be a $1600 camera right now, it can be an older second-hand one, because ultimately, if you have a good story, it doesn't matter what camera you use to tell it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always hire a camera cheaply for a project or if you have a project that you want to film then you could crowdfund that.